# Prevent user from saving locally

Tags: windows, group-policy, microsoft-office

I have a client requirement to block users from saving Office files (any Office app) locally, they should only be able to save files on the client's SharePoint to prevent data-loss at all costs.

I found about `Restricted Browsing` but this forces me to specify at least one local path, which does not suit the client's requirement.
I also tried to create an `Excel Add-In` with `VSTO` but it doesn't work correctly in Office 2016 (while it does in 2013).

Is there any other way I could try to do this?

**EDIT**

I have a possible workaround which would be to point the `Restricted Browsing` to a `read-only` folder to which the user has no `Write` permissions, but it provokes an awful user experience.

Comment: With Restricted Browsing you can set a UNC path as an approved location and I'm sure you could probably set a drive letter mapped to a network share as well. When you enable Restricted Browsing does it really "force" you to add a local path as an approved location? Have you tried setting only a UNC path or a drive letter mapped to a network share?

Comment: @joeqwerty I could try that out but since it's a new customer I don't have any information about their internal network. I'd rather just "hide" the "Save As > This PC" option if it was possible. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case I would do a RDS server and I would publish the office suite that way.

That would allow you to map the only letter you want the user to save in, and you block the mapping of the client drive at the same way.

Sadly that solution imply investment, but suit your scenario